# Make the ggplot2 legends horizontal and one row

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want my graph to look like this (please focus on the layout of the legend):

[image]

I have tried doing so with this code, but the legends don't exactly look the same.

```
  ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
   theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal") +
   scale_color_discrete(NULL) +
   guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1, nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are setting nrow and ncol to be one, and you are also setting the wrong guide - you should adjust the colour legend, not fill.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal") +
  scale_color_discrete(NULL) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]