I'm facing difficulty with fixing the direction of my guide legend
I'm debugging a script and my code runs smoothly from the top to bottom so far. However, the guide legend (the bubbles key) should line horizontally instead but I have no clue how to fix that. I've provided the code for this particular section below.
Graph:

I've tried manipulating the code in this section but it doesn't work in any way.
ggplot(data, aes(bill_length_mm, bill_depth_mm)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = means,
            aes(x = bill_length_means,ymin = bill_depth_means - bill_depth_sd,
                ymax = bill_depth_means + bill_depth_sd, color = species),
            inherit.aes = FALSE, width = 0.8, linewidth = 0.8) +
  geom_errorbar(data = means,aes( y = bill_depth_means,
                              xmin = bill_length_means - bill_length_sd,
                              xmax = bill_length_means + bill_length_sd,
                              color = species ), inherit.aes = FALSE, width = 0.5, linewidth = 0.8) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = species,  size = body_mass_g),  shape = 21,
         color = "transparent", alpha = 0.3)  + 
  geom_point(aes(size = body_mass_g ),  shape = 21, color = "white", fill = "transparent") +
  geom_text(data = labels,aes(x = x, y = y, label = species, color = species ),
        size = 5.6, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  annotate( "text",x = 37.5, y = 14.85,
        label = "Bubble size represents\nindividual body mass",
        color = "grey50",
        size = 3, lineheight = 0.9) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal,guide = "none" ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal, guide = "none") +
  scale_size(name = "", breaks = 3:6 * 1000,labels = c("3 kg", "4 kg", "5 kg", "6 kg")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(size = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom", 
                         override.aes = list(color = pal[2], stroke = .8, fill = NA))) +
  theme(legend.position = "inside",legend.position.inside = c(0.22, 0.15),
    legend.key.width = unit(.01, "lines"), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8, color = "grey50")) +
  labs( x = "Bill length (mm)", y = "Bill depth (mm)",
    title = "Bill dimensions of the Palmer penguins",
    subtitle = "Scatterplot of bill length versus bill depth (error bars show mean +/- standard deviation)")


Please do not add code as an image for these reasons. Instead, add the code in a codeblock. Also, it will be easier to help you if you make your question a minimal, reproducible example.

Try with guide_legend(nrow = 1, ...). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252017/make-the-ggplot2-legends-horizontal-and-one-row or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585693/how-to-turn-my-legend-horizontal-as-opposed-to-vertical-with-ggplot2.

@stefan Thanks for your reply! I tried that and it's producing a new legend with the species name instead, not with these bubbles.

Not sure what you tried. But guides(size = guide_legend(..., nrow =1)) works for me: https://i.sstatic.net/gwG6CQIz.png

@stefan Thank you so much! I've managed to do that now!!!
